# Как сделать задержку в итерациях цикла for?

Tags: java, android

Уже чего только не перепробовал, конструкция Handler и Runnable задерживается только 1 раз, не подходит. В моём цикле for производится действие и начинается новая итерация, но мне необходимо чтобы между "действие" и "итерация" было еще "задержка 1 сек"
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Применить sleep или pause, что там в яве

Comment: @Эникейщик sleep, но sleep на главном потоке приведет к тому, что приложение повиснет. Я пробовал создавать новый поток, но у него уже нет метода sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ThreadDemo {

public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println("Main stream");
    MyThread mr1 = new MyThread("Thread #1");
    MyThread mr2 = new MyThread("Thread #2");
    MyThread mr3 = new MyThread("Thread #3");
    MyThread mr4 = new MyThread("Thread #4");
    MyThread mr5 = new MyThread("Thread #5");
    
    for (int count=0;count<50;count++){
         System.out.print("@");
         try{
             Thread.sleep(400);
         }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               System.out.println(ex);
            }
    }
     System.out.print("End of main.");
}

}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
    String thrd="";
    Thread thrd1;
   MyThread(String Name){
       thrd = Name;
       thrd1 = new Thread(this);
       thrd1.start();
   }
  @Override
  public void run(){
      try {
        System.out.println("Запуска потока - "+thrd);
        for(int count = 0 ; count < 10;count++) {
            
                Thread.sleep(200);
            
            System.out.println("В - "+thrd+" ; счетчик - "+ count);
   
        }
         System.out.println("Конец");
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               System.out.println(ex);
            }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для "задержи" текущего потока:

```
Thread.sleep(количество_миллисекунд);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

Метод также может кидать InterruptedException. Надо либо заворачивать в try/catch, либо писать throws InterruptedException у метода.

Пример вывода чисел от 1 до 10 с паузой в секунду:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println("i: " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если задерживать главный поток, то приложение повиснет. Можно ли как-то создать новый поток и там реализовать его задержку?

Comment: Можно, например унаследовать класс от Thread, переопределить метод public void run()(туда и написать что должен делать поток), и в конструкторе запустить поток (this.start()). Но есть проблема, если два потока (тот что в main, и только что созданный) будут одновременно писать в консоль, то вывод пойдёт кашей. Такие ошибки в больших программах сложно ловить. Со сложной структурой тоже могут быть проблемы. Можно использовать, например, Semaphore. Туть есть документация - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html .